# How can i get links on flash objects (on my web page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I want to get all links in my flash object.
I have a flash object (it's src is not in my site) on my page and its changing always. I need to get link on flash (link inside on flash).

How can i do this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot "open" flash files. You will need to decompile and find it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have access to content in flash unless the flash movie exposed a method. Don't use flash if you need to modify it with js.

Comment: Web are using flash menus and i need to link my menu elements by <a href ... ></a> I don't want to put links by myself. My menus are changing by the templates and i have to check flash links with this method... Please help me.

Comment: Then you need to read config file in Flash and populate it in flash. This is a pretty big answer to post. I suggest you play around with flash and xml and then post a question.